# Selenium IDE - Click on all elements with the same class

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have many < i > with the same class = **"right icon icon- history etech-workorderlist-history-action"** and i'm trying to create a script who servs on clicking at all those  :

```
<td class="pure-datatable-col-site  pure-datatable-cell " id="yui_3_17_2_1_1499525618580_38262"> 01szazdvrr
<i class="right icon icon-history etech-workorderlist-history-action" title="Historique" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1499525618580_38264">
</i>
</td>
```

i wrote this but it only clicks on the first

```
 click
//i[@class="right icon icon-history etech-workorderlist-history-action"]
```

Comment: In your HTML there's a space in `icon- history` which doesn't appear in your XPath.

Comment: It was a mistake in HTML code. Thank's

Comment: Are you looping/iterating through the elements that selenium finds? I only see one click command and no loop, so I would expect only the first one to get clicked.

Comment: Yes i'm looping and it clicks on the same element during the loop

Comment: Yes i'm looping and it clicks on the same element during the loop